# React, timed loop updating DOM at once instead of updating in increments

Tags: css, reactjs, for-loop, settimeout

I am trying to visualize the Bubblesort algorithm using react.

*New to react, help appreciated - I saw similar questions but couldn't get it to work*

in my main **app.jsx** i have following code setup to create the necessary DOM elements:

```
...
let test_arr = [10, 4, 30, 7, 15, 5, 30, 6];

return (
    <div className="sorting_container">
         {test_arr.map((num, index) => (
             <DataBlock val={num} pos={index} key={index} />
         ))}
    </div>
);
...
```

The corresponding **DataBlock.jsx** component:

```
import React from "react";

class DataBlock extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.height_multiplier = 3.5;
        this.position_multiplier = 42;
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <div id={`DataBlock${this.props.pos}`} className="DataBlock"
                style={{
                    height: `${ this.height_multiplier * parseInt(this.props.val) }px`,
                    transform: `translateX(${ parseInt(this.props.pos) * this.position_multiplier }px)`
                }}
            >
                <label>{this.props.val}</label>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export { DataBlock };
```

using the above code I am able to generate my desired output:
[image]

**To simplify what I want:**
To visualize the algorithm I need to be able to change the styles of each DataBlock element.
To show you my problem I simplified the procedure by just changing each DataBlock's backgroundColor to red - in increments of 1 at a time and a pause of 1s between each change.

To achieve that I use "useEffect", inside my **app.jsx**, to call BubbleSort.jsx.

```
...
useEffect(() => {
        BubbleSort();
});
...
```

My **BubbleSort.jsx** file:

```
function BubbleSort() {
    let datablocks = document.getElementsByClassName("DataBlock");

    for(let i=0;i<datablocks.length;i++) {
        setTimeout(() => {
            document.getElementById(`DataBlock${i}`).style.backgroundColor = "red";
        }, 1000)
    }
}

export default BubbleSort;
```

The code changes all the elements from green background to red at once after 1s. I expect it to change each element seperately with 1s pauses. How can I achieve that or is my approach wrong from the beginning?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to timeout the for loop.
You can achieve this with `i * 1000` delay in timeout.
Try this;

```js
function BubbleSort() {
    let datablocks = document.getElementsByClassName("DataBlock");

    for(let i=0;i<datablocks.length;i++) {
        setTimeout(() => {
            document.getElementById(`DataBlock${i}`).style.backgroundColor = "red";
        }, i * 1000)
    }
}

export default BubbleSort;
```

Comment: It works perfectly. Thank you! I will mark this as the answer as soon as I'm able to